# Can't get CSS to give same padding on top/bottom as I get on sides

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the same amount of space between my .email-background class and my .email-container class all the way around the .email-container. But I have more space at the top and bottom, even though I specified a 10px padding all the way around. I've tried zeroing out margins for both elements.

```
`<style>
            div {
                    padding: 0px;
                    margin: 0px;
                }
        .email-background{

                          background: gray;
                          padding: 10px                       
                        }               

        .email-container{
                         background: #ccf2ff;

                         }
            .headerlogo {
                        margin-top: 30px;
                        border-radius: 30px;
                        border: 5px solid black;
                        max-width: 100%; 
                        display: block; 
                        margin: auto; 
                        width: 50%; 
                        margin-bottom: 40px;
                        }
        .comcastlogo{
                     max-width: 100%;
                     display: inline;
                     float: left; 
                     margin-left: 
                     12%; margin-bottom: 20px;      
                    }
    </style>

 </head> 
 <body>

     <div class="email-background">             

        <div class="email-container"> 
            <h1>Here is your September 2017 GPA Maintenance Newsletter</h1>         
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5xskeoF.jpg" alt="The newsletter logo" class="headerlogo">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/uhdSAow.jpg" alt="The comcast logo">
            <h2 style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15%;">September 2017</h2>          
        </div> 

     </div> 

</body> `
```

Comment: Please ignore the downvote on my answer - as you can see in the working snippet, it works perfectly. I can only assume someone was being petty because it pointed out the flaw in the other answer (which works in a way, but isn't precisely correct because it changes the other margins on your h1 and h2 which is an unwanted effect)  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra padding is coming from the elements inside the div. To fix it, you just need to remove space from the first and last elements, i.e.

- Remove the *top* padding & margin from the first element (`<h1>`)
- Remove the *bottom* padding & margin from the last element (`<h2>`)

**NOTE: Don't just set padding & margin to 0**, as it will affect the margin on the all other sides, which you don't want to change!

CSS:

```
/* remove the space from the top of the h1 */
.email-background h1 {margin-top:0; padding-top:0}
/* remove the space from the bottom of the h2 */
.email-background h2 {margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.email-background {
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px
}

.email-container {
  background: #ccf2ff;
}

.headerlogo {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.comcastlogo {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* remove the space from the top of the h1 */
.email-background h1 {margin-top:0; padding-top:0}
/* remove the space from the bottom of the h2 */
.email-background h2 {margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0}
```

```html
<div class="email-background">

  <div class="email-container">
    <h1>Here is your September 2017 GPA Maintenance Newsletter</h1>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5xskeoF.jpg" alt="The newsletter logo" class="headerlogo">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/uhdSAow.jpg" alt="The comcast logo">
    <h2 style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15%;">September 2017</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Why does this happen?**

The issue comes from something called "**margin collapsing**", where 2 adjoining vertical margins collapse to the highest of the two.

For a detailed explanation of margin collapsing see [Mastering Margin Collapsing from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

Comment: Why do you need to remove `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` in this case?

Comment: @NisargShah because the OP specifically asked about the padding -
 they said the problem was with the `padding:10px` added to the div. The margin was causing the collapsing margin problem, but they may *also* have been talking about the *inner* spacing caused by the padding they specifically asked about.

Comment: They are just referring to padding on `email-background`.

Comment: @NisargShah Their question wasn't particularly clear, the way it was phrased could be interpreted as the "space between" *and* "all the way around the .email-container" (as in, inner padding), so its unclear exactly what they require and that part of the question is open to interpretation. Either way, to fix the collapsing margin they should only reset the margin on the *top/bottom* of the h1/h2 elements.

Comment: *I specified a 10px padding all the way around* I think it is pretty clear. Also, should you post an answer while you are not clear of the question? :)

Comment: @NisargShah You really are determined to pick holes in my answer just because I pointed out the flaw in yours (downvoting it was particularly petty)! I never said I was unclear -
 I said that I interpreted the question one way, you interpreted it another. I answered the question I interpreted, and at least I addressed the crucial part correctly :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155151/discussion-between-nisarg-shah-and-fluffykitten).

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time, I found both answers useful. Fluffy Kitten, I appreciate that you advised only to amend the top of one element and the bottom of the other, so as not to cause unwanted effects.

Comment: @sunspore Glad I could help! If you were reading the comments above, you'll see that I also set the padding to 0 - this will remove any extra space in the inner padding of the `.email-background` div (The margin removes the extra spacing in the grey outer div). I'm not sure if you need to change the padding or not - I usually do for more consistent layout - but you can just remove the padding from the CSS if its not what you need!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the margin on `h1` & `h2` to `0px` to fix that.

```html
<style>
  div {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  
  .email-background {
    background: gray;
    padding: 10px
  }
  
  .email-container {
    background: #ccf2ff;
  }
  
  .headerlogo {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
  
  .comcastlogo {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  h1,h2 {
    margin: 0px;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="email-background">

    <div class="email-container">
      <h1>Here is your September 2017 GPA Maintenance Newsletter</h1>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5xskeoF.jpg" alt="The newsletter logo" class="headerlogo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/uhdSAow.jpg" alt="The comcast logo">
      <h2 style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15%;">September 2017</h2>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer? It is correct! Were you just being petty because it pointed out a flaw in yours?